# Extract specific items from list

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I would like to extract only the names that are from January, so that they appear in the January column, I've tried *=left()* and *=right()* but they don't seem to work. Any info on how to do this will help!

[image]

Comment: And please confirm do you need these outputs in `EXCEL` or `GOOGLE SHEETS`, though they look alike but functionality differs a lot! So please use proper hash tags!

Answer (score 2):

In C2 (under the "January" header), place this formula:

`=FILTER($A2:$A, $B2:$B=C1)`

This one formula would work without the `$` symbols. But I assume you're going to want to drag it to the right under other month names; so I wrote it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

So if you want return multiple records for a month, then you can use any one of the following formulas as shown in image below,

**FORMULA ALTERNATIVE ONE IN CELL C2**

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1)/($C$1=$B$2:$B$8),ROW(A1))),"")
```

**FORMULA ALTERNATIVE TWO IN CELL D2**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,SMALL(IF($C$1=$B$2:$B$8,ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROW(A1))),"")
```

This is an array formula and requires to press **CTRL SHIFT ENTER**

**FORMULA ALTERNATIVE THREE IN CELL E2** --> This works both in `EXCEL(ONLY EXCEL 2021 & O365) & GOOGLE SHEET`

```
=FILTER($A$2:$A$8,$E$1=$B$2:$B$8)
```

[image: EXTRACT & RETURN MULTIPLE RECORDS]